# How to repeat classList.add()

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to get all my elements to flash. The classList.add( "activated") turns each colour black and the classList.remove( "activated") turns all the elements back to their original colour. As you can see with the setTimeout() the elements flash black for 300ms. I want this to happen 5 times (the elements should flash 5 times in total). I have added a for loop that works (i tested it with alert()). However, im thinking that classList.add and remove dont work in the way I am hoping.

Any suggestions to repeat this flashing effect 5 times in a row?
'''

```
function ClickCheck(tile) {
const index = humSeq.push(tile) - 1;
const yellow = document.querySelector(`[data-tile='yellow']`);
const red = document.querySelector(`[data-tile='red']`);
const green = document.querySelector(`[data-tile='green']`);
const blue = document.querySelector(`[data-tile='blue']`);
const remainingTaps = seq.length - humSeq.length;
if (humSeq[index] !== seq[index]) {

    var times = 5;
    var i;
    over = true;

    if (over) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            yellow.classList.add('activated');
            red.classList.add('activated');
            green.classList.add('activated');
            blue.classList.add('activated');



            setTimeout(() => {
                yellow.classList.remove('activated');
                red.classList.remove('activated');
                green.classList.remove('activated');
                blue.classList.remove('activated');
            }, 300);


        }
    }

    resetGame();
    return;
}
```

Comment: The problem you are facing is that the timeouts are all being set at the same time asynchronously. An approach to this would be through recursive functions with recursive calls on timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a flash function that decrements a repeat counter each time it runs until there are none left. Something like this:

```js
function flash (element, duration = 500, repeat = 5) {
  // toggle the class
  element.classList.toggle('flash');
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    // revert it when the timeout expires
    element.classList.toggle('flash');
    
    // if we haven't reached the last repeat...
    if (repeat > 1) {
      // ...do it again after a delay
      setTimeout(() => flash(element, duration, repeat - 1), duration);
    }
  }, duration);
}

const div = document.querySelector('.demo');

flash(div);
```

```css
.demo {
  background: bisque;
  color: tomato;
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.flash {
  background: tomato;
  color: bisque;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">Do wookies wear hats?</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that the timeouts are all set at the same time.

You cannot do this in the way you are proposing as far as I'm aware, so an alternative approach to this would be to create a recursive function which calls on timeouts (similar to how `setInterval` works).

```
function PerformNTimes(startCallback, endCallback, delay, n) {
  if (n === 0) return;
  
  startCallback();

  setTimeout(() => {
    endCallback();
    PerformNTimes(startCallback, endCallback, delay, n - 1);
  }, delay);
}
```

`startCallback` is a function you want to run at the start of each loop. E.g., add the className.

`endCallback` is a function you want to run at the end of each loop. E.g., remove the className.

`delay` is the time between iterations (if you want a variable delay, you can pass an array and index by the iterations remaining.

`n` is the number of iterations you want the loop to go for.

I haven't tested if the code works perfectly, but I hope this is a sufficient explanation for you to work out how to solve this. Here is an example of the code running: https://jsfiddle.net/xuoc53kd/.

Comment: What does startCallBack, endCallBack and delay mean in this instance?. Im guessing n is how many times you want to repeat?

Comment: See the edits, I think that should clear it up. n you are correct about. The example should help as well if it is still unclear

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment your article ...
Can you plz say if you want active color after color or all in the same time
All in the same time :

```
async function ClickCheck(tile) {
  const obj = {
    yellow: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='yellow']`),
    red: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='red']`),
    green: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='green']`),
    blue: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='blue']`)
  }
  const index = humSeq.push(tile) - 1;
  if (humSeq[index] !== seq[index]) {
    new Array(5).fill(0).forEach(async (x) => {
      for (const property in obj) obj[property].classList.add('activated')
      await setTimeout(300)
      for (const property in obj) obj[property].classList.remove('activated')
    })
    resetGame();
    }
}
```

One after one

```
async function ClickCheck(tile) {
  const obj = {
    yellow: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='yellow']`),
    red: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='red']`),
    green: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='green']`),
    blue: document.querySelector(`[data-tile='blue']`)
  }
  const index = humSeq.push(tile) - 1;
  if (humSeq[index] !== seq[index]) {
    new Array(5).fill(0).forEach(async (x) => {
      for (const property in obj) {
        obj[property].classList.add('activated')
        await setTimeout(300)
        obj[property].classList.remove('activated')
      }
    })
    resetGame();
    }
}
```